# Protractor-Retrieve only first few elements from the map function & then check for assertion

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor

Is it possible to shrink the array contents returned by the map function ?

I need to use few elements from the array and then perform a match ?

My scenario is that i am taking all 10 urls in the array using map function & then i need to shrink it to 5 urls & then iterate & check all 5 urls if the name occurs within the top 5 results

```
var initial_array=element.all(by.xpath("//*[@id='panel_container']/div/div"));
let output_array=initial_array.map(function(element, index) {
         return {
           index: index,
           text: element.getText(),
         };

       });
output_array.then(function (refined) {
            console.log(refined.length);
            for (var i=0;i<refined.length-5;){
        if (expect(refined).toContain("URL address i am looking for"))
        {
            console.log("Found the Relevant answer within top 5 answers");

        }
        else{
         console.log("The Relevant answer is not within top 5 answers");
        }
            i++;
            }
```

The problem here is it gives me all 10 results & need to retrieve only first 5 elements from the map function & then check for the title match.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could try slicing the array returned from the map function.

Comment: You can set the position attribute in xpath to return first five results -- div[position() < 6]  (index starts at 1 not 0)...